# How to put the links in jspdf on the text in table? I am using the jspdf.link for making the links in the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, spfx, jspdf-autotable

[Code Snippet for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIFwp.png)

[In this Table of Sales Play Mapping ,i want to put the links on the Sales Play & Most Relevant Reference
Customer Column ][2]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Error you're getting? You currently have a comment in your code saying "link is `undefined`". I'm guessing this refers to `mostRelevantCustomer.link`. I would need more details to give you an answer.

Comment: @BeniTrainor I am unable to generate the link on this , that comment is just a note for, but we are having the links stored in the object for mostRelevantCustomer and SalesPlays. THis is the snippet of code

Comment: @BeniTrainor Please let me know if you need more information, can we connect over the google meet for that?

Comment: Hey @Vivek. for the question and answers to be relevant in StackOverflow you need to provide a minimum reproducible example. Also, it would be better if the code and error messages are in text (not images). As for doing online meetings, I prefer to stay on StackOverflow. This way others can benefit from the troubleshooting.